# Adding Roles to Blazor.BFF.OpenIDConnect.Template Fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

Hell.  I am trying to use this template (https://github.com/damienbod/Blazor.BFF.OpenIDConnect.Template)  and extend it to also use Roles.  When I add the following code, the Authorize attribute works if I don't include the Role.  But, if I include the Role, it will fail with a 403 error when I try to hit the controller.

**Server Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

**Server UserController.cs**

//hardcode the Admin role to test:

```
var claims = claimsPrincipal.FindAll(userInfo.NameClaimType)
   .Select(u => new ClaimValue(userInfo.NameClaimType, u.Value))
   .ToList();
 claims.Add(new ClaimValue("role", "Administrator"));
 userInfo.Claims = claims;
```

**DirectApiController.cs**

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DirectApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() => new List<string> { "some data", "more data", "loads of data" };
}
```

When this code runs, I can see that the "role" called "Administrator" gets added to the user.  But, when the function SendAsync, in the AuthorizedHandler class is called, this function:

```
responseMessage = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

will run and return a 403 Forbidden error.  How can I add roles to this Blazor WASM Core hosted app?

**EDIT:**

I went and did a new deployment and I think the issue is not on the Server authorization but the Client.  I kept it very simple.  In the Server Program.cs file I added this to the ​AddOpenIdConnect method:

```
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>{  
   context.Princepal?Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "Administrator"));
}
```

Then in my Controller, I added this Attribute: `[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]` and this works fine.  But, in the razor page, when I add either this:

```
<AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator">
</AuthorizeView >
```

or

```
@attribute[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
```

The razor page will say it is not authorized to view the content.  If I remove the Role requirement (and just have Authorize) it works fine.  It doesn't seem like it recognizes the Role claims?

Comment: What seems odd is that the @attribute [Authorize (Roles ="Administrator")] attribute works on the client side Razor pages.  Just not in the Server side controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  I realized I needed to include all claims in UserController.cs ile